# How to add more file types to the FancyUpload plugin?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, mootools

I am trying to modify the [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/) plugin to accept the following files extensions.

- *.jpg
- *.jpeg
- *.txt
- *.gif
- *.png
- *.doc
- *.docx
- *.pdf
- *.xlsx
- *.ppt
- *.pdf

I have already searcher, but all the topics about this are outdated, and it doesn't work. This plugin has two files, `index.php` and `scrip.js`, where there are the same filter. I have already changed that with this but nothing works.

This is what I have tried so far:

**index.php**

```
    $('demo-browse').addEvent('click', function() {
        swiffy.browse();
        return false;
    });

    $('demo-select-images').addEvent('change', function() {
        var filter = null;
        if (this.checked) {
            filter = {'docs (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.txt, *.gif, *.png, *.doc, *.docx, *.pdf, *.xlsx, *.ppt, *.pdf)': '*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.txt; *.gif';*.png, *.docx, *.pdf;*.xlsx;*.ppt;*.pdf};
            //filter = {'Images (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.png)': '*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.png'};
        }
        swiffy.options.typeFilter = filter;
    });
```

**script.js**

```
    $('demo-browse').addEvent('click', function() {
        swiffy.browse();
        return false;
    });

    */
    $('demo-select-images').addEvent('change', function() {
        var filter = null;
        if (this.checked) {
            filter = {'docs (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.txt, *.gif, *.png, *.doc, *.docx, *.pdf, *.xlsx, *.ppt, *.pdf)': '*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.txt; *.gif';*.png, *.docx, *.pdf;*.xlsx;*.ppt;*.pdf};
            //filter = {'Images (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.png)': '*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.png'};
        }
        swiffy.options.typeFilter = filter;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just visited this page, and copy the script there: [solution](http://www.rioleo.org/getting-fancyupload-to-work.php), but I still dont figure out other things but well, fancyupload has a avandced coding